# Does exec directly jump to the new proccess it creates? Or by kernel interrupt?

Tags: linux, unix, process, operating-system, exec

In UNIX, a new process is started by `exec` system call. And as to how the new process is started, the book *Operating Systems Principles and Practices* states that, firstly OS allocates new memory for the new process, then stores initial states to the kernel interrupt stack, and finally starts the process by exiting kernel using the `popad` and `iret` instruction, which set the processor states to the states stored in kernel interrupt stack and jumps to the code address stored in the kernel interrupt stack.

But I wonder, why not just set initial states and jump to new process directly within the `exec` function?

And is there anything wrong in my statement as to how a process is started by kernel interrupt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In UNIX, a new process is started by `exec` system call.

Not really. `fork` or `clone` create a new process. `exec` will replace the currently running program by another program inside an **existing** process.

> But I wonder, why not just set initial states and jump to new process directly within the exec function?

This would mean that you want to emulate `exec()` completely on user level (using `open()`, `read()` etc.) instead of using the kernel.

In many cases this would theoretically be possible. However, there are some cases where this is not possible. (Think about a file with `-rws--x--x` access rights!)

And it would require the entire file format interpreter to be in the `exec()` function on user level. Especially when using statically linked executables each program calling `exec()` must contain the code that parses the file format of executable files.

Different programs might support different file formats in this case: Some programs written for Linux kernels 1.2.13 would be able to run both (the then newly introduced) *ELF* and *a.out* executables while others would only be able to run *a.out* files; not all programs could be started by all programs.

A kernel implementation (using a system call) will support or not support a certain file type independently of the program that calls `exec()`.

The next problem is that the user-level implementation might "forget" some de-initialization code: Let's say you use an `exec()` implementation written for Linux 2.4 and you call the `timer_create()` system call. Because the `exec()` implementation does not know that such timers exist, it would not stop the timer.

A kernel implementation (using a system call) knows all features of the operating system and therefore cleans up the "old program" completely before starting the new one.

Answer (score 1):

[Exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) does **NOT** create a new process. [Fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) does.

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image
> with a new process image.

Inspecting glibc implementation of [_execve](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/mach/hurd/execve.c.html#__execve)

```
/* Replace the current process, executing FILE_NAME with arguments ARGV and
   environment ENVP.  ARGV and ENVP are terminated by NULL pointers.  */
```

You can dive into details and see how it is implemented.

---

> But I wonder, why not just set initial states and jump to new process
> directly within the exec function?

That's how threads work, a process has it's own state, with its own priority, file descriptors, interrupt table and more.